# Auto-populating created_by field with Django admin site

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to use the Django admin interface for a very simple web application but I can't get around a problem that should not be that hard to resolve ..

Consider the following:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False)
```

I can't find a way to auto-populate the created_by field and make the Django admin aware of it. Most of the method I've seen implies overloading the Object's save method and pass it the request user. They all requires to build your custom views and/or forms.

Optimally the form to create new contacts *in the admin site* should not show the created_by field (which is quite easy) and auto-populate it with the current user (which seems harder than it should).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookNewformsAdminAndUser

Involves implementing save methods on your ModelAdmin objects.

Comment: This was very helpful and it led me to the docs page, which is even better because it lets you select your version of Django!  E.g., version 1.6: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify a [default](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default) for the field, in this case a method call that gets the current user (see the auth documentation to get the current user).

Answer (score 2):

I did it by overriding the save_model method in django admin. Since you mentioned that you wanted to use the Django admin interface. So, I think my solution will be the most appropriate one. The solution goes like this:

1. First register the Contact model in the admin by excluding the 'created_by' field

> ```
> @admin.register(Contact)
> class Notice(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     list_display = ('name', 'created_by')
>     exclude = ('created_by', )
> ```

2. Then override the save_model method in the same class Notice

> ```
> def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change,):
>     obj.created_by = request.user
>
>     super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I really wanted a better solution than the ones I found elsewhere, so I wrote some middleware - implementation on the [Populate user Id question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12977709/795488). My solution requires no changes to any form or view.