# Django: Populate user ID when saving a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I have a model with a created_by field that is linked to the standard Django User model.  I need to automatically populate this with the ID of the current User when the model is saved.  I can't do this at the Admin layer, as most parts of the site will not use the built-in Admin.  Can anyone advise on how I should go about this?

Comment: This [blog entry](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/nov/02/django-tips-auto-populated-fields/) discusses exactly that.

Comment: This post is pretty old. Is there an easy way to achieve this now?

Comment: @seanf What's the answer to this?

Answer (score 40):

> **UPDATE 2020-01-02**
>   ⚠ The following answer was never updated to the latest Python and Django versions. Since writing this a few years ago packages have been released to solve this problem. Nowadays I highly recommend using `django-crum` which implements the same technique but has tests and is updated regularly: https://pypi.org/project/django-crum/

The least obstrusive way is to use a `CurrentUserMiddleware` to store the current user in a thread local object:

### current_user.py

```
from threading import local

_user = local()

class CurrentUserMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        _user.value = request.user

def get_current_user():
    return _user.value
```

Now you only need to add this middleware to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES **after** the authentication middleware.

### settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    ...
    'current_user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

Your model can now use the `get_current_user` function to access the user without having to pass the request object around.

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from current_user import get_current_user

class MyModel(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', default=get_current_user)
```

### Hint:

If you are using Django CMS you do not even need to define your own CurrentUserMiddleware but can use `cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware` and the `cms.utils.permissions.get_current_user` function to retrieve the current user.

Comment: Seems thorough but in django 1.6.2 and Python 3.3.2 I receive the following error extract when I use south ```./manage.py schemamigration app --initial``` :```return _user.value
AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'value'```

Comment: That is right as the middleware is never called. For South (and probably a lot of other management commands) to work you need to catch the `AttributeError` in `get_current_user` and return `None`.

Comment: Thank you! `Your model can now use the get_current_user function to access the user without having to pass the request object around.`. Is this the reason why using a middleware class is better practice than using [this snippet](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookNewformsAdminAndUser) or they can be considered as equivalent solutions?

Comment: @rara_tiru It depends on your needs. By using a thread local object and a middleware ANY object saved during the request with an authenticated user will fill the `created_by` field. The snippet only patches the admin.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seem too clean to me, maybe just because I haven't gotten used to it yet, but I like the fact that this can be done. I was starting to get the impression that it was entirely impossible to reach arbitrary variables in a model function, in fact some people have outright stated as much. Thanks for sharing this. +1

Answer (score 36):

If you want something that will work both in the admin and elsewhere, you should use a custom modelform. The basic idea is to override the `__init__` method to take an extra parameter - request - and store it as an attribute of the form, then also override the save method to set the user id before saving to the database.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
       return super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       kwargs['commit']=False
       obj = super(MyModelForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       if self.request:
           obj.user = self.request.user
       obj.save()
       return obj
```

Comment: I'm unable to figure out how to make the admin to initialize MyModelForm with 'request' object. Is it even possible without modifying the contrib.admin code itself?

Comment: If using class based views it is very important to see Monster and Florentin's answers below, they are essential steps.

Comment: but what about having acces to it in `pre_save` of model? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305186/accessing-in-passing-to-django-models-signal-methods-like-pre-save-pre-delete

Comment: just to complete the answer. To be able to access `request` object in `__init__` , it must be passed when initialising your form in your view. Ex: `myform = MyForm(request.POST, request=request)`

Comment: way late...but how would this be modified for a modelformset in views.py?

Comment: the syntax of `super(MyModelForm, self)` [changed in python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), just call `super()`

Comment: what is the problem with using something like:     ```def save(self, user):
        obj = super().save(commit = False)
        obj.user = user
        obj.save()
        return stuff```. and then call it like `myform.save(request.user)`

Comment: Please add the comment of @vincebodi to the answer

Answer (score 27):

Daniel's answer won't work directly for the admin because you need to pass in the request object. You might be able to do this by overriding the `get_form` method in your `ModelAdmin` class but it's probably easier to stay away from the form customisation and just override `save_model` in your `ModelAdmin`.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    """When creating a new object, set the creator field.
    """
    if not change:
        obj.creator = request.user
    obj.save()
```

Comment: Tim Fletcher, hello, i get an error if save_model is defined in admin.py when trying to create a new entry(model object of a class and that class has m2m field): "'MyClass' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.". Can you advice what should be added?

Answer (score 15):

This whole approach bugged the heck out of me. I wanted to say it exactly once, so I implemented it in middleware. Just add WhodidMiddleware after your authentication middleware.

If your created_by & modified_by fields are set to `editable = False` then you will not have to change any of your forms at all.

```
"""Add user created_by and modified_by foreign key refs to any model automatically.
   Almost entirely taken from https://github.com/Atomidata/django-audit-log/blob/master/audit_log/middleware.py"""
from django.db.models import signals
from django.utils.functional import curry

class WhodidMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.method in ('GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'TRACE'):
            if hasattr(request, 'user') and request.user.is_authenticated():
                user = request.user
            else:
                user = None

            mark_whodid = curry(self.mark_whodid, user)
            signals.pre_save.connect(mark_whodid,  dispatch_uid = (self.__class__, request,), weak = False)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        signals.pre_save.disconnect(dispatch_uid =  (self.__class__, request,))
        return response

    def mark_whodid(self, user, sender, instance, **kwargs):
        if 'created_by' in instance._meta.fields and not instance.created_by:
            instance.created_by = user
        if 'modified_by' in instance._meta.fields:
            instance.modified_by = user
```

Comment: The best answer. I ended up using getattr(instance, 'pk') to determine whether my models were being created.

Comment: This code is not thread safe. If you are using a WSGI container that uses threads (e.g. Apache2 + mod_wsgi, uWSGI, etc.) you can end up storing the wrong user.

Comment: This code is indeed not thread safe; probably better to avoid in production environments

Comment: @giantas this code is conceptually wrong. You need to use a `thread local` object for this to work properly. In doubt just use `django-crum` which works and is correct: https://pypi.org/project/django-crum/

Answer (score 10):

here's how I do it with generic views:

```
class MyView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel

    def form_valid(self, form):
        object = form.save(commit=False)
        object.owner = self.request.user
        object.save()
        return super(MyView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: call `form.save()` again, not `object.save()`, in case there are commit-dependent customizations in the `save()` method (which anyway will call `save()` on the model instance)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using class based views Daniel's answer needs more. Add the following to ensure that the request object is available for us in your ModelForm object

```
class BaseCreateView(CreateView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """
        Returns the keyword arguments for instanciating the form.
        """
        kwargs = {'initial': self.get_initial()}
        if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
            kwargs.update({
                'data': self.request.POST,
                'files': self.request.FILES,
                'request': self.request})
        return kwargs
```

Also, as already mentioned, you need to return the obj at the end of ModelForm.save()

Answer (score 4):

what is the problem with using something like:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ['created_by']

    def save(self, user):
        obj = super().save(commit = False)
        obj.created_by = user
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

Now call it like `myform.save(request.user)` in the **views**.

here is [ModelForm's save function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/66b6b689239dad3f017d2a3495df748cbee5debb/django/forms/models.py#L443), which has only a `commit` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

For future references, best solution I found about this subject:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-crum/0.6.1

This library consist of some middleware.
After setting up this libary, simply override the save method of model and do the following,

```
from crum import get_current_user        


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = get_current_user()
    if not self.pk:
        self.created_by = user
    else:
        self.changed_by = user
    super(Foomodel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

if you create and abstract model and inherit from it for all your model, you get your auto populated created_by and changed_by fields.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [bikeshedder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/994342/bikeshedder)'s answer, I found a solution since his did not actually work for me.

1. app/middleware/current_user.py

   ```
   from threading import local

   _user = local()

   class CurrentUserMiddleware(object):

   def __init__(self, get_response):
       self.get_response = get_response

   def __call__(self, request):
       _user.value = request.user
       return self.get_response(request)

   def get_current_user():
       return _user.value
   ```
2. settings.py

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE = [
       'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

       'common.middleware.current_user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
   ]
   ```
3. model.py

   ```
   from common.middleware import current_user
   created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, related_name='created_by', editable=False, default=current_user.get_current_user)
   ```

I'm using python 3.5 and django 1.11.3

Comment: while running ./manage.py migrate, I get the following error: `AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'value'` which makes sense as the request middle ware is not loaded during migration. Or did I missing something here? Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 2):

From the Django documentation [Models and request.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user):

> " To track the user that created an object using a CreateView, you can
>   use a custom ModelForm. In the view, ensure that you
>   don’t include [the user field] in the list of fields to edit, and override
>   form_valid() to add the user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'save' method from forms.ModelForm returns the saved instanced.

You should add one last line to MyModelForm:
...
return obj

This change is necessary if you are using create_object or update_object generic views.
They use the saved object to do the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Daniel's answer is the best there is since it changes the default behaviour of a model form by always saving the object.

The code I would use:

## forms.py

```
from django import forms

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super(MyModelForm, self).save(commit=False)

        if obj.created_by_id is None:
            obj.created_by = self.user

        if commit:
            obj.save()
        return obj
```

Answer (score -5):

Note sure if you were looking for this, but adding the following

```
user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

to a model will work to add the user id to the model.

In the following, each hierarchy belongs to a user.

```
class Hierarchy(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
```