# Django: Save User ID with Model Save

Tags: django, django-models

My question is very similar to this question:  [Django: Populate user ID when saving a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862522/django-populate-user-id-when-saving-a-model)

Unfortunately I did not quite understand their answer.

When a user logs in I want them to be able to submit a link and I have a user_id foreign key that I just can't seem to get to populate.

```
def submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddLink(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = AddLink()

    return render_to_response('links/submit.html', {'form': form})
```

Everytime I submit my form it mentions:

```
null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Which I understand but what I don't know how to add user_id to the my form object.  How can I access the currently logged in user's id and submit it along with my form data?

Answer (score 12):

You can do something like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    link = form.save(commit=False)
    link.user = request.user
    link.save()
```

commit=False allows you to modify the resulting object before it is actually saved to the database.

Comment: I saw that...  Is this the best way of doing it?  Something like this seems really common and I figure their would of been something "automatic."

Comment: Remember to check if the user it logged in in your view.
The <code>@login_required</code> decorator is quite nice for this :-)

Comment: Well, you could insert the user_id into a hidden field in the form, but this is the way in normally done.

Comment: Right-O,  What do you think about the answer from piquadrat?

Comment: Well, it works :-) It's up to you which way seems best, both will work, but the commit=False method is the documented way of doing this.

Comment: @Klette: Inserting the user_id into a hidden form field is UNSAFE: a malicious user could insert a different user_id than his own.

Answer (score 6):

replace your `if form.is_valid()`-block with this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.user = request.user
    form.save()
    return redirect('home')
```

Comment: I am using the way you suggested, an it works. What I am failing at, is to save user id in child model instance. I am using model forms and inline formset for creating related model instances. Any suggestions?