# Django ModelAdmin.save_model() -vs- ModelAdmin.save_formset()

Tags: django, django-models

I want to ensure that a user editing a particular model is saved in that models `updated_by` (FK User) field.

I'm using mostly ModelForms (not necessarily the built in Admin), and wondering:

In what cases would I need to override `ModelAdmin.save_model()` or `ModelAdmin.save_formset()`**?**

Or, is that doing it wrong? If it's just the models' `save()` method that needs to be overridden, is there a proper way to access the `request` object there?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862522/django-populate-user-id-when-saving-a-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was previously answer by [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862522/django-populate-user-id-when-saving-a-model).

> If you want something that will work both in the admin and elsewhere, you should use a custom modelform.

He provides an example and points to [this blog post by James Bennett](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/nov/02/django-tips-auto-populated-fields/).