# Question about Django Accessing and saving User Foriegnkey in my model

Tags: django, django-authentication

I see that [similar to this has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862522/django-populate-user-id-when-saving-a-model) but I would like to know if there was a simpler way to achieve this.

Also followed [this blog post](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/nov/02/django-tips-auto-populated-fields/).

A sample Model is given below.

```
class Post (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, help_text="required, name of the post")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    modified_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    custom_hashed_url = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=1000, editable=False)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #How to save User here?
        super(Model, self).save()
```

Isn't it possible to send current logged in user to the Model before calling save()?

In the view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

if not errors:

    f = PostForm(request.POST)

    f.save()
```

Comment: I have been looking for a solution to this problem. My user is logged in, I have the foreignkey setup, but it gives me an error `Cannot assign None: "MyModel.user" does not allow null values.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you've tagged this with `django-admin`, I'll assume you're wishing to save the `User` who is modifying the object via the admin interface. (You can't really do it in your model's save method, because it doesn't necessarily have access to a `User` object -- e.g. what if you're saving an object from a shell interface?)

To do this within Django's admin, simply override the `save_model` method of your `ModelAdmin`:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Of course, you would need to actually add a `ForeignKey` named `user` to your model for that to work...

Comment: I see. So then, how to do people save User in their models if there is a User Foreignkey ?

Comment: You just need to add `user = models.ForeignKey(User)` to your model. Then the above code should work fine.

Comment: I agree but this is from the admin interface. Is there any easy way to do that from my app, using django's auth.

Comment: Only if you have access to the request object, in which case solutions don't come much easier than the original link you posted -- a model form which saves a reference to the request and extracts the user from that upon save.

Comment: I have been looking for a solution to this problem. My user is logged in, I have the foreignkey setup, but it gives me an error `Cannot assign None: "MyModel.user" does not allow null values.`

Comment: Where/how are you saving your object? In admin, using a `ModelAdmin` with `save_model` as described above? If elsewhere, please post your code.

Comment: I cannot post code properly on this so here is the Google Doc... http://goo.gl/CdLsZ . ... I am not using it in the Admin section or ModelAdmin. I want my website to save users who posted stuff if they are logged in.

Comment: Isn't it possible to send current logged in user to the Model before calling save()?

Comment: @User007: there is no such thing as "the current logged in user" -- there could be hundreds of users currently logged in, it depends which one made the request, which is why you need the request object.