# Setting user_id when saving in view - Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to set the user that is creating the post in the add view:

```
@login_required 
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BusinessForm(request.POST)
        form.user_id = request.user.id
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('listing.views.detail'), args=(f.id))
    else:
        form = BusinessForm()
    return render_to_response('business/add.html', {'form':form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I assign the user id `form.user_id = request.user.id` but when saving, it still gives me an error `Column user_id cannot be null`

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

EDIT:

I am excluding the user from the form in the model:

```
class BusinessForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Business
        exclude = ('user',)
```

Could that be causing the problem?? How can I work around this?

EDIT 2:

Edited my BusinessForm() class as suggested but did not work:

```
class BusinessForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Business
        exclude = ('user',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        return super(BusinessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['commit']=False
        obj = super(BusinessForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request:
            obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.save()
```

Business model

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    website = models.URLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='business_pictures',blank=True)
```

Comment: I don't think that excluding a field should cause a problem, checkout [this](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/nov/02/django-tips-auto-populated-fields/) for an example of how to achieve what you want

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have to use `init` or `save` overrides for this.

You're just setting an attribute on your form and the form doesn't do anything with it. It doesn't magically behave like a model instance (your form wouldn't have a `user_id` attribute).

Since your form is a `ModelForm`, you can simply call save on it with [`commit=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) to get the unsaved instance, set the user, then call `save` on the instance.

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BusinessForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        business = form.save(commit=False)
        business.user = request.user
        business.save()
```

Comment: You sure? That should not happen. Use the original ModelForm with only the Meta class and no init/save overrides.

Comment: Yes. Wouldn't this fail the validation? Since it does not have a user Id?

Comment: The reason you've excluded the user is to bypass validation. No problem!

Comment: This comment needs to be posted somewhere in giant big letters. I wasted a good two hours trying to modify my `__init__` and `save` methods so I could simply set the user_id in the model to request.user.id. The logic is so obvious once you point it out. Thanks

Comment: @Cole, I added that you don't need to override init or save in the first line!

Comment: @Yuji Unfortunately, this particular StackOverflow answer does not appear as high in google search results, leading no doubt many people down a particularly unnecessary rat hole. What should have always been obvious to me is that when you `save(commit=False)`, you get a model object. An a model object is so much more useful than a form object, and so much easier to understand, because they are such a big part of Django. Forms seem to be more of an environmental hazard. Thanks again for your awesome answer.

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/862870/1114171) seems to be exactly what your looking for.

Comment: Tried and doesn't seem to work... I added the __init__ and save methods to the BusinessForm(ModelForm) class

Comment: Is your user_id field related to the user model (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey), also in your `Business` model is the member user_id or user?

Comment: added business model to question

Comment: so then I think originally where you have form.user_id = request.user.id it should be form.user = request.user.id (maybe without the `.id`)

Comment: @TomIngram the user model field would only exist on the model instance - not a django form. Setting attributes won't fail, but it won't do anything.

Comment: @YujiTomita hi and thanks, your comment has just made something click in my head. For clarity a call to an (un)committed save on a form returns it's 'supporting model', and a forms properties are only 'representative' of the 'supporting model' not the model object's actual properties?

Comment: Hey Tom, calling save with commit or not on a ModelForm will always return a model instance. A form doesn't contain attributes that reflect the form / model fields at all. They are not represented as direct properties at all -- the form fields exist in form.fields and the validated data in form.cleaned_data. The forms will not know to do anything with attributes assigned to it e.g. form.fieldname = 'foobar'. I'm on a smartphone so excuse the formatting - hope that clears it up for you!