# showing the model values of specific user django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to show the data of a user which he has entered. This is my model

```
class IgaiaContent(models.Model):
    CONTENT_CHANNELS = (
        ('YouTube','Youtube'),
        ('FaceBook','FaceBook'),
        ('Flickr','Flickr'),
        ('Instagram','Instagram'),
    )
    content_name =          models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    content_type =          models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    content_source =        models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, choices=CONTENT_CHANNELS)
    content_location =      models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    content_latitude =      models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,null=True)
    content_longitude =     models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,null=True)
    content_embed_code =    models.TextField(null=True)
    content_description =   models.TextField(null=True)
    content_tags_user  =  models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)  
    content_time_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content_time_updated =  models.DateField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.content_name
        return self.content_type
        return self.content_source
        return self.content_location
        return self.content_latitude
        return self.content_longitude
        return self.embed_code
        return self.description
        return self.tags_user 
        return self.time_uploaded
        return self.time_updated



tagging.register(IgaiaContent)
```

My view

```
def create_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AuthorForm1(request.POST) 
            if form.is_valid(): 
                    form.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
            form = AuthorForm1()

    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('portal/form1.htm',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My form template:

```
<form method="post" style="height: 553px; width: 594px">
<div class="style12">

{% csrf_token %}

        </br>{{ form.as_p }}

</div>
</form>
```

thats how i am showing my model values

```
employee_info1 = {
    "queryset" : IgaiaContent.objects.all(),
    "template_name" : "portal/emp1.html",
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',


    (r'^view5/',  list_detail.object_list, employee_info1),
)
```

emp1.html

```
{% if object_list %}
<table>
<ul>
{% for item in object_list %}
   <li>{{item.content_name}}</li>
   <li>{{item.content_type}}</li>
   <li>{{item.content_source}}</li>
   <li>{{item.content_location}}</li>
   <li>{{item.content_latitude}}</li>
   <li>{{item.content_longitude}}</li>
   <li>{{item.content_embed_code}}</li>
   <li>{{item.content_description}}</li>
   <li>{{item.content_tags_user}}</li>
   <li>{{item.content_time_uploaded}}</li>
   <li>{{item.content_time_updated}}</li></ul>
{% empty %}
   <td colspan="11">No items.</td>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endif %}
```

It is not displaying specific user value means it is displaying me everything.
can anyone tell me how to show specific user values/data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your model so that it contains a field to store the user -

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class IgaiaContent(models.Model):
    #...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Then you need to create a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862522/django-populate-user-id-when-saving-a-model).

```
class IgaiaContentForm(forms.ModelForm):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
       return super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       kwargs['commit']=False
       obj = super(MyModelForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       if self.request:
           obj.user = self.request.user
       obj.save()

   class Meta:
        model = IgaiaContent
```

Now update your view so that that you use your new ModelForm

```
def create_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = IgaiaContentForm(request.POST) 
            if form.is_valid(): 
                    form.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
            form = IgaiaContentForm() 
    #...
```

Now in your object_list view you do something like -

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def object_list(request):
    #....
    object_list = IgaiaContent.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render_to_response('object_list_template.html', {'object_list': object_list})
```

Comment: thanku soo much :) i am making a view like this def object_list(request):
    object_list = IgaiaContent.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return object_list(request,queryset=list_detail.object_list, template_name='portal/emp.html')

Comment: but it is giving me error 'QuerySet' object is not callabe..can u plz tell me why?

Comment: I've updated my code. Read about writing views - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/views/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response