# Django AttributeError at /accounts/profile/ 'User' object has no attribute 'get' while update profile

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Hello i get the following error when i tried to add form to update description of the user profile

My models :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_img = models.ForeignKey(Image,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='images',null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
```

My form :

```
class ChangeUserDescription(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['description','profile_img']
        widgets = {
            'description': forms.Textarea(),
            'profile_img':forms.ImageField()
        }
        labels = {
            'description':'Description',
            'profile_img':'Image'
        }
```

My view :

```
@login_required
def profile(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChangeUserDescription(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
    else:
        form = ChangeUserDescription(request.user)
    return render(request, 'registration/profile.html', {'form': form})
```

And my template :

```
<div class="mainPage">
    <h1>Profile</h1>
    
    <h2>Bonjour {{user.get_username}}</h2>
    
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
    </form>
      
    
    
    <a href="{% url 'adoptYourOcApp:password_change'%}" >Change password</a>


    {% include "annonces/my_list.html" %}
</div>
```

Direclty when i go on the corresponding page i get the following error :

```
AttributeError at /accounts/profile/
'User' object has no attribute 'get'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/profile/
Django Version: 2.2.17
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'User' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: In django, the default queryset operations are started with the objects manager, so the form internally should be calling `User.objects.get()` instead of `User.get()`.
Please, take a look at your codebase, perhaps there are redefined form classes somewhere.
Are you using any additional packages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate your `ModelForm` `ChangeUserDescription` with an actual instance of `Profile`, e.g. `ChangeUserDescription(instance=profile)`.

```
some_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
form = ChangeUserDescription(instance=some_profile)
```

and similar when updating:

```
form = ChangeUserDescription(request.POST, instance=some_profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue probably lies in the way you initialize your form.
You can look at the API reference for `ModelForm` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm

```py
class ModelForm(BaseModelForm, metaclass=ModelFormMetaclass):
    pass
```

It doesn't define an `__init__` method, so we look in it's parent `__init__`, namely `BaseModelForm.__init__`.

```py
class BaseModelForm(BaseForm):
    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
                 initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None,
                 empty_permitted=False, instance=None, use_required_attribute=None,
                 renderer=None):
```

As you can see there, it doesn't accept the `instance` as a positional argument, but rather a keyword one.
The first argument in init is `data=None`, so your form instance is treating the `request.user` you passed as a data dictionary, thus calling the nonexistent `.get()`

Fixing your code to

```py
form = ChangeUserDescription(request.POST, instance=request.user)
```

Should solve the case.

Credit: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184415/user-object-has-no-attribute-get)