# Django middleware 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I have problem with middleware I found a lot of questions about it but nothing help in my case.

I use middleware to get current_user to use in my model to save modified user in save method without write this in view.

Here is [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862522/django-populate-user-id-when-saving-a-model) with this code:

**Middleware**

```
from threading import local

_user = local()


class CurrentUserMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        _user.value = request.user


def get_current_user():
    return _user.value
```

**There is something wrong in this code because I'm getting error like:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 158, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 53, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = mw_class()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
[20/Jul/2016 10:51:44] "GET /panel/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 158, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 53, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = mw_class()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
[20/Jul/2016 10:51:44] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

**My middleware settings:**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware',
    'task.current_user',
)
```

Can you give me some advice where is error or something? I don't have any other idea to try so I hope that you have some.

Comment: Please show your middleware settings. Also, **never ever do this**.

Comment: @DanielRoseman what u mean never ever do this? / I updated questions and add middleware settings

Comment: what's inside task.curreny_user.py? can I see your project tree structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must give the full path of your middleware **class**. Not the module containing the middleware.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware',
    'task.current_user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
)
```

Note that you had plenty of examples right above.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my custom middleware missed the **call** method. So you can try to check your custom migrations and add **call** method if it's missed. Django recommends this code as default one:

```
    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware