# Attach a newly created object to the current user in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Assume I have a Django application where a user may create a fantasy football team `Team`. This is accomplished using `TeamCreateView`, a regular `CreateView` (class-based generic). The `User` model has a field called `my_team`, which by default is empty. What is the best way to ensure that after `User` creates a new `Team`, `my_team` will be set to the newly created model instance?

Edit: models, as requested:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    # ...some other stuff

class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=127)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    my_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=True, blank=True)
```

The relationship is 1-to-1, but cannot be done as a OneToOne field as they are going to be created at different times. That is, the way the business process is structured calls for a user to first create an account (creating the `User` entity), and then either get invited into an existing team or create a team. The `Team` is created using a generic `CreateView`, and my main objective is to attach the `Team` to the User using the `my_team` field.

Comment: You have a foreign key on `Team` in `User`? Want to show your model?

Comment: Shouldn't this be the reverse(ie, a user field in the Team model) so that a user can create multiple teams if you decide to allow that in future? It will still work in your current scenario as well

Comment: Any way, you can override the save method of the model to achieve the functionality you need

Comment: @Manu How? You cannot access the request in the model's save method, or can you?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Indeed. Please see update above.

Comment: Will this help?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862522/django-populate-user-id-when-saving-a-model

Comment: I stand corrected. request is not accessible from the save method, so you have to handle this from your view itself.