# Making a custom Boolean field in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django rest framework.
The relevant part of my models looks something like this (simplified):

```
class Action(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField()
    bonus = models.IntegerField()

class User(models.Model):
    auth = models.OneToOneField(AuthUser)
    display_name = models.CharField()

class Comment(models.Model):
    contributor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()

class Activity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    target_comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment)
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
```

I want one of my API endpoints to be able to return something like this:

```
{
    ...
    "comments":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            ...
            "curr_user_upvoted": true
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I know the query I need to execute in order to get the value for "curr_user_upvoted", but I don't know how to make it part of the API representation.
I know how to create custom relational fields, but it doesn't help since "curr_user_upvoted" is neither a field nor a relation.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to do this. This is just a method on the serializer class that returns the value you want.

The method name defaults to `get_curr_user_upvoted` - in other words it should be `get_` followed by the field name, though you can pass an explicit `method_name` parameter to the field if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some solutions to this .

1. First using the serializer method field .

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    curr_user_upvoted = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id', 'curr_user_upvoted')

    def get_curr_user_upvoted(self, obj):
        return obj.activity_set.filter(
            user=self.context['request'].user,
            action__type='upvote' 
        ).exists()

class MainSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True)
```

2. adding it to the model class.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    contributor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()

    def curr_user_upvoted(self):
        user = get_current_user()
        self.activity_set.filter(
            user=user,
            action__type='upvote' 
        ).exists()


class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    curr_user_upvoted = serializers.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id', 'curr_user_upvoted')


class MainSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True)
```

you can get the current user using this way

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786764/14387799

3. adding a custom field

```
class CurrentUserUpvotedField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return instance.activity_set.filter(
            user=self.context.get('request').user,
            action__type='upvote'
        ).exists()


class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    curr_user_upvoted = CurrentUserUpvotedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('id', 'curr_user_upvoted')


class MainSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True)
```

for this to work you'll need to add pass the request to the context

```
MainSerializer(data, context={"request": request)
```