# How to create pre_populated_field in admin django like slug

Tags: python, django, auto-populate

i want create a custum *auto populated field* in admin **django** like slug but calculate another thing , not slugify.
how do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, what have you tried?
There are couple of answers around, and they all talk about the same thing.. Hooking on the `save_model` method.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change): 
    obj.some_field = "some_value"
    obj.save()
```

You can look the following:

[Django: Populate user ID when saving a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862522/django-populate-user-id-when-saving-a-model/12977709#12977709)

[Auto-populating created_by field with Django admin site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855816/auto-populating-created-by-field-with-django-admin-site)

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookNewformsAdminAndUser