# Auto created_by field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In one of my models i have a `created_by` field. I want this to be automatically set to the user that created the instance. I saw this: [Auto-populating created_by field with Django admin site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855816/auto-populating-created-by-field-with-django-admin-site)

However, that only works with the admin site and doesn't work with django rest framework. Any ideas on what I could do? Thanks

Comment: You can write some middlware to automatically set this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/862522/67579

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks! Would you recommend https://pypi.org/project/django-crum/ or writing it myself?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple methods for doing this.

The easiest method is the one suggested by the documentation (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save) :

> Passing additional attributes to .save()
>
> Sometimes you'll want your view code to be able to inject additional
> data at the point of saving the instance. This additional data might
> include information like the current user, the current time, or
> anything else that is not part of the request data.
>
> You can do so by including additional keyword arguments when calling
> .save(). For example:
>
> `serializer.save(owner=request.user)`

Or you can overwrite the `.create()` method of your serializer, and use `self.context`:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    bar = serializers.CharField()
    created_by = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)  # FK

    def create(self, validated_data):
        created_by = get_object_or_404(User, user=self.context["request"].user)
        foo = Foo()
        foo.bar = validated_data["bar"]
        foo.created_by = created_by
        foo.save()
        return foo
```